# Greedy implementation using dictionary in python with multiple 'trips'

Tags: python, sorting

This code is just to load a file in as a dictionary.
The dictionary has the format `(name,weight)`

```
def load_cows(filename):
    #define empty dictionary
    d = {}
    #open file, iterate through each line and store name and number
    with open(filename,'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            (key,val) = line.split(",")
            d[key] = int(val)
    return d

x=load_cows('testdoc')
```

My issue is with the greedy 0-1 knapsack approach I am trying to implement. Mainly the fact that I want to make more than 1 'trip'. I would like to represent 'trips' as a list of lists where the lists represent trips.

See my attempt below

```
def greedy_cow_transport(cows, limit):
    
    #base case
    if cows == 0 or limit == 0:
        return 0
    
    trips = [[]]
    total = 0
    trip_count = 1
    #sort dictionary with largest weight on the left and smallest weight on the right
    cow_sort = {key: val for key, val in sorted(cows.items(), key = lambda ele: ele[1], reverse = True)}
    
    
    while (len(cow_sort)!=0):
        for i in cow_sort:
            if ((cow_sort[i] + total) < limit):
                trips.append(i)
                total += cow_sort[i]
            else:
                trip_count += 1
                trips *= trip_count
            
            
                
            
    
    return trips

greedy_cow_transport(x,10)
```

Here is the error I got when run

```
MemoryError:
```

Any help would be appreciated, apologies for any ambiguities I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: You have `while (len(cow_sort)!=0)`. What makes you think that this condition will ever become `False`?

Comment: Why did you bother showing us how you load the dictionary? Am I missing its relevance somehow? If not, please remove it. Instead, show a sample of the actual inputs you are using. No one but you has access to the text file, and we don't need to see it in the raw.

Answer (score 1):

Found few problems with your code.

1. You should store `current_trip` somewhere and append it to `trips` when you cannot put next cow inside
2. Your while condition has no sense, you should just iterate over cows.
3. You should reset `total` somewhere.
4. You don't need trip count, it's just len of `trips`
5. You can iterate over dictionary keys/values at once

Code after improvements:

```
    trips = []
    current_trip = []
    for cow_name, weight in cow_sort.items():
        if (weight + total) > limit: # next cow is to heavy
            trips.append(current_trip) # add saved trip
            current_trip = [] # and clear it
            total = 0

        current_trip.append(cow_name) # Our new cow starts new trip then
        total += weight

    trips.append(current_trip) # Add the last trip

    return trips
```

Do not forget to serve the case when the heaviest cow is heavier than limit!